# doppler graph using an audio file

Tags: sound

I'm trying to plot a graph frequency (Hz) x Time (ms). My problem is, I dont know what kind of data I'm extracting from the audio file. When I write the function: `data = Import[sampleaudio, "Data"]` How can I isolate the frequency?

This is my audio file, i'm using a frequency generator. It generates 1000hz. https://www.dropbox.com/s/60i7he0ppq6y7al/001f.wav?dl=0

Comment: Show sample `sampleaudio`, pls.

Comment: I've attached the audio file I'm talking about.

Comment: See Help ref/AudioLocalMeasurements